# JSSOR not w3 valid

Tags: validation, jssor

Ok so the guys at JSSOR.com have made a great plugin, however according to w3 it is not valid. Can they or anyone on here please tell me how I can change `U="slider"` to `id="slider" or name="slider"` basically something that is valid.

Comment: you can use data-u (data-u="slides") instead. Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/pass-html-validation.html